# Port redirection on FTP

Tags: port-forwarding, ftp

I'm setting up an FTP server and when I try to download a file using port 21 it works fine. I'm using IIS and I simply set other ports in the bindings section [IIS configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3NZL.png)

When I try to download it using other ports (tried 22, 24 and 990) it seems the request is redirected internally to a different port each time [request result over 10 tries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq1VD.png).

The error is clear I just don't understand why it's being redirected to a different port each time.

[Source code used for downloading file (c#)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MChFE.png)

[Successful with port 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8jOi.png)

[Unsuccessful with port 24](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwOmT.png)

WinSCP Log (port 21):

> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.410 Using FTP protocol.
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.410 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.441 PWD
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.460 257 "/" is current directory.
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.460 Getting current directory name.
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.511 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.511 TYPE A
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.530 200 Type set to A.
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.530 PASV
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.549 227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,222,161,206).
>
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.549 LIST -a
>
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.549 Connecting to ***.***.***.222:41422 ...
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.568 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.586 04-04-22  01:54PM                 Software
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.586 Data connection closed
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.586 226 Transfer complete.
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.586 Directory listing successful
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.586 Detecting timezone difference...
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.586 Found no file to use for detecting timezone difference
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.586 Warning: Timezone difference was not detected yet, timestamps may be incorrect
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.586 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T02:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.586 Software;D;0;2022-04-04T11:54:00.000Z;1;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
> 2022-06-14 15:32:08.605 Startup conversation with host finished.
> 2022-06-14 15:32:38.454 Sending dummy command to keep session alive.
> 2022-06-14 15:32:38.454 PWD
> 2022-06-14 15:32:38.454 257 "/" is current directory.

WinSCP Log (port 990):

> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.897 Connected
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.897 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.913 PWD
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.931 257 "/" is current directory.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.931 Changing directory to "/".
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.931 CWD /
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.949 250 CWD command successful.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.949 Getting current directory name.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.950 PWD
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.969 257 "/" is current directory.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:40.972 Startup conversation with host finished.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:41.035 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2022-06-14 15:08:41.035 TYPE A
> 2022-06-14 15:08:41.053 200 Type set to A.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:41.054 PASV
> 2022-06-14 15:08:41.071 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,10,218,16).
> 2022-06-14 15:08:41.071 Server sent passive reply with unroutable address 192.168.1.10, using host address instead.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:41.072 LIST
> 2022-06-14 15:08:41.072 Connecting to ***.***.***.222:55824 ...
> 2022-06-14 15:08:41.091 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:56.655 Timeout detected. (data connection)
> 2022-06-14 15:08:56.656 Could not retrieve directory listing
> 2022-06-14 15:08:56.703 (EFatal) **Lost connection.**
> 2022-06-14 15:08:56.703 Server sent passive reply with unroutable address 192.168.1.10, using host address instead.
> 2022-06-14 15:08:56.703 Timeout detected. (data connection)
> 2022-06-14 15:08:56.703 Could not retrieve directory listing
> 2022-06-14 15:08:56.703 Error listing directory '/'.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not sure which logs you are referring to but I have added 2 new screenshots one with port 21 where the file is downloaded successfully and one with port 24 with the error I'm getting

Comment: I have added the log from WinSCP using port 990

Comment: Don't use port 22. It is reserved for SSH and all sort of weirdness can happen if the router or the server itself has SSH in use.

Comment: I'm trying on ports 22, 24 and now I included in my tries port 990 because on WinSCP when I select FTP/Implicit encryption it pre-selects port 990 so I figured there might be some pre-configured stuff there that might help out (same error as the other ports)

Answer (score 1):

FTP does not work over (just) port 21. Port 21 only has the control connection. Data connections are *always* on different ports, traditionally even connected in reverse (server to client, so-called Active FTP).

When you use port 21 (and an unencrypted connection), NAT devices (and/or firewalls in general) can see which ports the data connection will need and act accordingly. If you use a different port, the FTP helper will not pick up this information. Data ports will remain blocked.

In your log, there is a dead giveaway:

> Server sent passive reply with unroutable address 192.168.1.10, using host address instead.

This means your FTP server is behind NAT but doesn’t properly support it.

Comment: The FTP Server will probably properly support it, but the router doing the NAT doesn't handle FTP properly if it is not using the standard port-numbers. In some routers you can get it to work by 1st enabling the NAT rule for FTP on the standard port-number and then change the port-number from 21 into the desired number. Just adding a custom port-forward rule for the port directly will never work as the router won't know you intend to use it for FTP.